# Get the value of an attribut and paste it in jQuery

Tags: html, jquery

So, I have 2 buttons each having an attribute and a value inside it. Now In my jQuery code, I'm trying to paste the value of the attribute of which of that buttons was clicked.

So the problem here is this when I click one of the buttons it doesn't update the value in cookies from that attribute. I also get something else as a value when clicked on one of the buttons. I left a screenshot down below.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WG9xx.png)

```js
$(document)['ready'](function() {
  $("[accent-switcher]").each(function(accentSwitcher) {
    $(this)['click'](function() {
      ips['utils']['cookie']['unset']('ipsTheme_type');
      ips['utils']['cookie']['set']('ipsTheme_type', $(this).val($(this).attr("accent-switcher")), true)
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button class='ipsButton' accent-switcher="blue">Color A</button>
<button class='ipsButton' accent-switcher="yellow">Color B</button>
```

Comment: Where did you learn to use syntax like `$(this)['click']` instead of `$(this).click`?

Comment: What is wrong with it, if may I ask?

Comment: It's highly non-idiomatic (also replacing `.` with `['` and `']` bloats the code and makes it harder to read).

Comment: It works, but it's not how anyone else writes method calls.

Comment: Please read [ask]. You've told us what you want to achieve, but you haven't said what problem you are having.

Comment: Well my bad then, I'm new at this. I'm just trying to understand it, anyway. I really need to understand how I can make that code work. It's really important to me.

Comment: There's no need to use `.each()` to add event handlers. jQuery updater functions automatically loop over collections.

Comment: There's no `accent-switcher` attribute in HTML. [`data-*` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) are a standard way to include custom data on an element.

Comment: Anyway, I think your code should work. What is `ips.utils.cookie.set()`?

Comment: I see the problem. `$(this).val($(this).attr("accent-switcher"))` should just be `$(this).attr("accent-switcher")`

Comment: `[object Object]` happens when you convert an object to a string - `$(this).val(...)` returns `$(this)` which is then being stored as a string - as above, you probably wanted `$(this).attr("accent-switcher")` if you're trying to store the attribute.

Comment: @Barmar that is this https://invisioncommunity.com/cookies, I want to create a color changer on software that already has some functions integrated for cookies, for example **{{if \IPS\Request::i()->cookie['ipsTheme_type'] == 'blue'}}accent-blue{{endif}}**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead, this should work, or try the 'run code snippet' button to test it out for yourself

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( "html body .ipsButton" ).on( "click", function() {
        var accentSwitcher = $(this).data('accent-switcher');
        alert('accent-switcher:' + accentSwitcher);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
    <body>
        <button class="ipsButton" data-accent-switcher="blue">Color A</button>
        <button class="ipsButton" data-accent-switcher="yellow">Color B</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please explain your answers. Games of spot-the-difference aren't very helpful.

Comment: This code will check for buttons with the .ipsButtons class, and then when one of these buttons is clicked it will display the accent-switcher value related to that button in an alert message

Comment: please run the code snippet to test it out

Comment: Well, thank you centralhubb.com. With your code and mine combined, I managed to do it, thank you very much! Have a lovely day.

Comment: sure thats ok i am glad it works, you have a great day as well, thanks